# python how to convert Special string u'\x08' u'\x09' u'\x03' to 8 9 3

Tags: python, string

use crypto encrypt string in Go.

PKCS7 Padding for ciphertext, because ciphertext must be a multiple of the block size (16).

```
exa:   ciphertext is : 123456789abcde. (len:14) 
       pandding:  []byte("123456789abcdef") + []byte(2) + []byte(2)
```

Python decode:

```
list: [u'1', u'2', u'3', ...,u'd', u'e', u'\x02', u'\x02']
```

now, can not get u'\x02'  to number 2.

Comment: What is this question about Python or Go?

Comment: yes, \x02 is not 2, but i want to get  2.

Comment: this question is  about python,but  have a better idea that can not  generate u'\x09'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by andars

```
c = ord(u'\x02') + ord('0')
print chr(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is not the best way to do this in python, but I tend to think in C, so here goes. It is probably pretty bad according to most people, but it gets the job done.

```
c = u'\x02'
byte = bytearray(c, 'utf-8')[0]
print(chr(ord('0') + byte))
=> 2
```

Comment: ho, it is work.  but  pandding  []byte(10)  that is not  work . python  list print “\n” . decode  not u'\x10' . :(

Comment: The above only works for single digits, as appeared in your question. Beyond that, I'm not sure what encoding you are using. Continuing the pattern, 10 would be u'\x0a', not u'\x10'.